# Give an example of a metric space $(X,d)$, a point $x_0$, and a radius $r>0$ such that $\bar B = C$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space, $x_0 \in X$ and for any  $r>0$. Let $B = \{ x \in X : d(x,x_0) \lt r \}$ and $C = \{ x \in X : d(x,x_0) \le r \}$.

Give an example of a metric space $(X,d)$, a point $x_0$, and a radius $r>0$ such that $\bar B \ne C$

-

Having trouble figuring out what exactly this question requires me to formulate. Am I supposed to go by the textbook definition or use the previous question: "Show that $\bar B \subset C$"?  (Which, by the way, I could only understand conceptually but couldn't quite find an appropriate example of how such a thing would be showed.)

Comment: Isn't this the case for $X=\mathbb{R}$ with the usual metric? Or is the question about finding $\bar{B}\ne C$?

Comment: What's your definition of $\overline B$? Try to use that to show $\overline B\subseteq C$. Any point and radius will give you an example of $\overline B=C$ in $\mathbb R^n$ with the standard metric.

Comment: @egreg Yes, that's right! I mean $\bar B \ne C$. Will edit as appropriate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume $\bar{B}\not\subseteq C$; then there is $x\in \bar{B}$ such that $x\notin C$, so $s=d(x_0,x)>r$. Consider the open ball $B(x,s-r)$; since $x\in\bar{B}$ we have
$$
B\cap B(x,s)=B(x_0,r)\cap B(x,s)\ne\emptyset
$$
so there is $y\in B(x_0,r)\cap B(x,s-r)$; therefore
$$
s=d(x_0,x)\le d(x_0,y)+d(y,x)<r+(s-r)=s
$$
which is a contradiction. Therefore $\bar{B}\subseteq C$.

You cannot prove that $\bar{B}=C$, because it's generally false: consider a (nonempty) set $X$ and the discrete metric
$$
d(x,y)=\begin{cases}
0&\text{if $x=y$}\\
1&\text{if $x\ne y$}
\end{cases}
$$
Then we have, for $x_0\in X$ and $r=1$,
$$
B=\{x\in X:d(x_0,x)<1\}=\{x_0\}=\bar{B},
$$
whereas
$$
\{x\in X:d(x_0,x)\le1\}=X
$$
so the equality $\bar{B}=C$ doesn't hold (every subset is closed with respect to the discrete metric) provided $X$ has at least two elements.

However, the equality *can* hold: take $X=\mathbb{R}$ with the usual metric
$$
d(x,y)=|x-y|
$$
Then the closure of $\{x\in \mathbb{R}:d(x_0,x)<r\}$ is $\{x\in \mathbb{R}:d(x_0,x)\le r\}$ for every $x_0\in\mathbb{R}$ and every $r>0$.

Comment: Thank you! I'll mull over this proof and try to absorb the definitions.

Answer (score 1):

The situation you describe can also happen with the Euclidean metric. Equip $X = [0, 1] \cup \{2\}$ with this metric. For $x_0 = 0$ and $r = 2$, we have $\overline B = [0, 1]$ and $C = [0, 1] \cup \{2\}$.

Answer (score 0):

If I have not overlooked anything, choose $X=\Bbb R$, $d(x,y)=|x-y|$.

$x_0=0$, $r=1$, and then we have $B=\{x\in\Bbb R:d(x,0)\lt 1\}$, which is the unit open ball.

$C=\{x\in\Bbb R:d(x,0)\le 1\}$ which is the closed unit ball, and indeed $\overline{B}=C$.